# Converting to Horn Form from CNF

Tags: prolog, sat-solvers

How do you convert a CNF clauses to a Horn form using Prolog? I am trying to create a SAT Solver that has CNF as an input, which will be need to convert to Horn form.

Comment: It might help if you defined what Horn form is and how it is different from the CNF format you're using, since CNF can be used to encode Horn formulas.

Comment: This does not make much sense imho. Being very informal: solving CNF is NP-hard, solving HornSat is in P. This means (using basic arguments by contradiction): complexity-wise, this transformation is as hard as solving the original CNF-SAT (NP-hard) and the output might be of exponential-size (not much you can do then with your HornSAT solver)!

Comment: Kyle Jones, how can CNF be used to encode Horn formulas?

Comment: sascha, so do you suggest me to just use in CNF

Comment: I don't suggest anything, but every *good* sat-solver works on cnf! Of course cnf can encode horn-formulas, as every horn-formula is a valid cnf (horn = much less powerful / much more constrained). 'What's unclear about the [wiki article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horn_clause)?

Comment: thanks sascha, i think i understand a little now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Horn clauses are a subset of CNF. Namely CNF can be viewed as conjunction of general clauses, where every clause has the following form and where Ai,Bk are propositional variables and n>=0 and m>=0:

```
A1 v .. v An v ~B1 v .. v ~Bm
```

The Ai are the positive literals and the ~Bk are the negative literals. Horn clauses are now those general clauses which have in maximum one positive literal, i.e. n=<1. Namely which are of either of the form as follows:

```
A1 v ~B1 v .. v ~Bm

~B1 v .. v ~Bm
```

Now its impossible to convert every CNF into Horn Clauses, even if we would allow changing the sign of a literal in the representation. Take this formula nae(A,B,C)=(A xor B) v (B xor C) and the relevant sign changing variants as CNF:

```
nae(A,B,C)       = (~A v ~B v ~C) & (A v B v C)
nae(A,B,~C)      = (~A v ~B v C) & (A v B v ~C)
nae(A,~B,C)      = (~A v B v ~C) & (A v ~B v C)
nae(A,~B,~C)     = (~A v B v C) & (A v ~B v ~C)
nae(~A,B,C)      = (~A v B v C) & (A v ~B v ~C)
nae(~A,B,~C)     = (~A v B v ~C) & (A v ~B v C)
nae(~A,~B,C)     = (~A v ~B v C) & (A v B v ~C)
nae(~A,~B,~C)    = (~A v ~B v ~C) & (A v B v C)
```

They are all non-Horn Clauses so a renaming translation is not possible. But maybe using other reductions, possibly non-polynomial ones, can be used to translate CNF to Horn Clauses.

P.S.: The nae(A,B,C) example is taken from [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schaefer's_dichotomy_theorem#Properties_of_Polymorphisms).